# table relationship and how to use it in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, relationship

so, I have 2 tables, stage and event. Stage hasMany event, and Event belongsTo Stage. And I want to show all stage and its event as json. Here is my code in controller:

```
public function getschedule(){
    $schedule = Stage::all();

    //$event = Event_schedule2020::all();
    if (!$schedule) {
      return response()->json(['msg'=>'Error not found','code'=>'404']);
    }

    foreach($schedule->events as $array){

        $datax[] = [
          'id'=>$array->id,
          'time'=>$array->time,
          'category'=>$array->category,
          'type'=>$array->title,
          'designer'=>$array->designer,
        ];
      }

      foreach ($schedule as $item) {
        $jadwal[] = [

          'id'=>$item->id,
          'date'=>$item->date,
          'place'=>$item->stage,
          'data'=>$datax,

        ];
      }

   return response()->json($jadwal);
  }
```

but I always get this error

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95oB6.png)

so, is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize inbuilt functions to do what you want to. Laravel automatically transforms model into `JSON`, no need to built arrays with it.

```
public function getschedule() {
    // tell laravel you want to eager load events
    $stages = Stage::with('events')->get();

    // laravel knows you loaded events and therefor you can just return it and it does the rest automatically
    return response()->json($stages);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your **Stage** model you have to create relationship like this

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}
```

then in your **Controller**

```
public function getschedule(){

   $schedules = Stage::with('events')->get()->toArray();

   return response()->json($schedules );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is call `events` on a collection for solve this you can change foreach like followings :

```
public function getschedule(){
  $schedules = Stage::all(); // I add a 's' to $schedule because is better set plural name;

  if (!$schedule) {
    return response()->json(['msg'=>'Error not found','code'=>'404']);
  }

  foreach($schedules as $schedule){

    $datax = [];
    foreach($schedule->events as $event){
        $datax[] = [
          'id'=>$event->id,
          'time'=>$event->time,
          'category'=>$event->category,
          'type'=>$event->title,
          'designer'=>$event->designer,
        ];
     }

     $jadwal[] = [
        'id'=>$item->id,
        'date'=>$item->date,
        'place'=>$item->stage,
        'data'=>$datax,
      ];
  }

  return response()->json($jadwal);
}
```

This solution is not recommended because send many request to server in any foreach loop, following solution is better:

```
    public function getschedule(){
      $schedules = Stage::with('events')->get(); // only this difference with above solution and the rest is the same
  if (!$schedule) {
    return response()->json(['msg'=>'Error not found','code'=>'404']);
  }

  foreach($schedules as $schedule){

    $datax = [];
    foreach($schedule->events as $event){
        $datax[] = [
          'id'=>$event->id,
          'time'=>$event->time,
          'category'=>$event->category,
          'type'=>$event->title,
          'designer'=>$event->designer,
        ];
     }

     $jadwal[] = [
        'id'=>$item->id,
        'date'=>$item->date,
        'place'=>$item->stage,
        'data'=>$datax,
      ];
  }

  return response()->json($jadwal);
}
```